# Change API display order in Swagger (using Django REST Framework)

Tags: django-rest-framework, swagger

I'm using the `django-rest-framework` and `django-rest-swagger` to generate and display my API respectively.  They're working beautifully.  But...

I'd like to change the order that my models are being displayed in the Swagger schema view.

I have:

[image]

This order seems strange (not alphabetical, or based on any of my code I can find) but consistent (always the same) to me.

I would like (for example) the "phages" model to be first in the list.

**How can I reorder these?**

Comment: Have u figured it out?

Answer (score -1):

Django Rest Swagger will follow the order you insert the urls in your code.

For instance, something like:

```
# ...
url(r'^phages', include('phages.urls')),
url(r'^subclusters/', include('subclusters.urls')),
# ...
```

this will get phages at the top.

Comment: So if I'm using the `router` I can't do it?  I need to explicitly specify each set of URLs?

Comment: You're right, I did not used the router. However, you do have an order inside the router and have to register the router in your urls the same way .. I think djang-rest-swagger will follow that as well. But I can't confirm that.

Comment: In my case the URL's show in alphabetical order @jarussi can you check and confirm the same?